# Emphasizing Cycles Render Ambient Occlusion

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, light, ambient-occlusion

I've tried the Ambient Occlusion (AO) option in the World tab but it brightens the scene too much and doesn't much increase the AO (in Cycles).

How can I increase the amount of Ambient Occlusion in a Cycles render?

Comment: I personally consider the Ambient occlusion option in the World tab as a quick way to get some AO. For fine tuning I usually use the compositor after enabling the needed passes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recommend you render the AO pass and do it in post-production for more control.

**1. Enable the AO pass in render layers.**

[image: Render layers]

**2. Open the node editor, enable Use nodes and do the following:**

[image: AO]

- The RGB Curves node controls the contrast and the darkness of the AO, which can be helpful.
- The AO pass is a Grayscale image so you need to multiply it with the render result.

## Additional Explanation

In Cycles, the *Ambient Occlusion* option in the *World* tab is technically an additional homogeneous direct lighting (almost like adding an additional solid white world background lighting). However the *Ambient Occlusion* in Blender Internal can act as additional shading (like **Multiply** blending in image editor programs or in the compositor). The *AO* pass in Cycles is basically the shadow data only, which you can use the get the Blender Internal behaviour back, or use in other ways.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Renderlayer material setting to override all materials with a ambient occlusion material:

[image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: To make this a complete solution, this layer would need to be **multiplied** on top a combined pass with a Mix RGB node.