# Quick way to model low poly cliffs / mountains?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

Is there any quick way to create low poly cliffs / mountains like those:

[image]
[image]

I tried to model something manually vertex by vertex, connecting with edges, then faces, really manual simple technique but it took ages just to make 1 wall like this:

[image]
[image]

My final task is to cover whole racing game map like this:

[image]

With such sharper rocks / cliffs. First two images are mesh created by someone in 3ds, I have access to and rights to use it but as it's imported it doesn't have any modifiers preserved or anything (I don't have access to original .max file nor 3ds as software) and somehow I highly doubt it was created vertex by vertex (especially editing this way is extremely inefficient in 3ds due to its inconvenient mesh edit modificator). When I even think about modelling all those mountains and cliffs vertex by vertex it makes me sick and I'd estimate it for at least 20h of work if I was about to really model whole map vertex by vertex.

We don't aim futuristic polygon style, more like conventional cartoon style. This is older map done in our style: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DUnthV8SuuA

Comment: Look at http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52521/low-poly-mountain-terrain It has some good awnsers

Comment: This thread has different scale I need something much more detailed. This is more like what I need: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58507/how-to-model-low-poly-nature-terrain but whereas original picture is indeed what I'd like to achieve, result reproduced by guy who gave explanation isn't really that great. I'd also like smooth shading with only few sharp edges not this common polygon style graphics.