# Ambient Occlusion with Cycles

Tags: rendering

So far I've been using the following setup to render the pure object-shadow in a studio environment. Rendered with BlenderRender and than composed in Photoshop.

[image: AO]

But since the fact [BlenderRender will be removed in 2.8](https://www.blendernation.com/2018/04/19/blender-internal-renderer-removed-from-2-8/) I'm searching for the same result in Cycles. There is this new Shadow Catcher option but I'm missing settings for factor and distance. Rendering an AO Pass only gives me a gray object color with shadows.

Comment: Eevee, which will replace blender internal has the controls you need for ambient occlusion. Watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_PA6rziWLS4

Comment: Look at: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51751/emphasizing-cycles-render-ambient-occlusion

Comment: @cegaton: I'm not talking about realtime-AO. I want to have full control of AO in a separate image.

Comment: @JakobSachs: This method doesn't give me settings like factor and distance.